# How to force Android app bundle to install all ABIs in google play?

Tags: android, google-play, apk, android-app-bundle

Need to disable split by abis when installed by google play, app is not built using gradle, we build it using apktool.
Basically I need all abis to be downloaded from googleplay.

Comment: Why?  A device has a single ABI, the other files are literally useless.  You'd be increasing package size to no benefit to anyone.

Comment: I really need to make it for my app to work propertly.

Comment: No, you don't  An app can work with split ABIs, if they couldn't it wouldn't exist.

Comment: I need some 32 bits libs to be installed too in all devices. Is it possible to make all abis install instead of split install?

Comment: If you're still running 32 bit libraries, you need to update them.  Pretty soon they won't be supported at all.  Nobody makes 32 bit devices anymore, and Google is looking to phase it out.  In fact you can't mix 64 and 32 bit libraries in Android-  you can use 32 bit libraries only if all of your libraries are 32 bit.  In which case you wouldn't need to worry about split ABIs either.

Comment: Also, Google play won't allow apps that don't have 64 bit versions of all their libraries.

Comment: But is it possible to make android bundle install all abis?